# Renaming files the name of the folder

Tags: windows

I have over 1500 folders in each folder is one item with a horrible name.

So
Awesomefoldername/crappyfoldername.iso
Awesomefoldername2/crappyfoldername.iso

What I’m hoping is by the end all the iso files have the awesomefoldername.

So
Awesomefoldername/Awesomefoldername.iso
Awesomefoldername2/Awesomefoldername2.iso

Please Help.

Comment: this isn't a free coding service. There are lots of batch renaming questions here, please show what you've tried and where you're stuck

Comment: I apologize I was on here because I saw someone else post on here a question. I’m sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry use it as  learning experience. You likely need `Get-ChildItem`, `ForEach-Object`, `Rename-Item` if you do it with PowerShell.

Comment: You can experiment with the following: `gci C:\test -Recurse -Filter *.iso |%{ ren $_.FullName $($_.Directory.BaseName+".iso") -WhatIf}` to get you going.  Note the WhatIf means it will just print what it would do.